# can't add dependency to build.gradle

Tags: android

So my android app won't compile with the following which is copied from socket.io website

```
   dependencies {
        implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:2.0.0') {
            exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
        }
    }
```

however just this  `implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:2.0.0')` compiles

what is the difference and how to fix it? Maybe this is why my app isn't working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://gradlehero.com/how-to-exclude-gradle-dependencies/
that links explains thats groovy syntax not kotlin syntax